# How to install let's Encrypt on Amazon Linux

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, letsencrypt

How do I install Let's Encrypt Certificates on amazon Linux I already have a WordPress website hosted.

Can anyone tell me the steps how do i start with it and what are the commands and what permission I should change and how do i edit ssl.conf and add certificates and auto renew.

Comment: This walkthrough is awesome for setting up let's encrypt with certbot. [https://nouveauframework.org/blog/installing-letsencrypts-free-ssl-amazon-linux/](https://nouveauframework.org/blog/installing-letsencrypts-free-ssl-amazon-linux/)

Answer (score 7):

Amazon's EPEL doesn't seem to have certbot for me.  Try manually installing it, here's a pair of articles with full instructions:

Try https://ivopetkov.com/b/let-s-encrypt-on-ec2/ for Apache

Or https://coderwall.com/p/e7gzbq/https-with-certbot-for-nginx-on-amazon-linux for Nginx

Short of it is:

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
chmod a+x certbot-auto
sudo certbot-auto certonly --debug --standalone -d yourdomain.com
```

`--debug` is required because Amazon Linux isn't well tested with certbot.  Replace `--standalone` with whichever certbot plugin you perfer.  Essentially just replace the standard examples' usage of `certbot` with `certbot-auto`.

Probably best if you check every once in a while for certbot to actually show up in Amazon's EPEL repo and/or to re-download certbot-auto in hopes of getting bug fixes/improvements.

### **UPDATE for "Amazon Linux 2"**

There's finally a certbot package in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) Yum Repositories.

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install certbot
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Although I think that the links will last longer than the relevance of the specific answer, I've added a summary.

Comment: This did not work for me on Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09 - it kept dying here:
```Nothing to do
Creating virtual environment...
./certbot-auto: line 652: virtualenv: command not found
```

needed to install python's virtualenv as well:

```yum install python26-virtualenv.noarch````

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions online; I think you have to keep on trying until you find one that works for you. After *a lot* of experimentation, what worked for me was following the certbot instructions for Apache and CentOS 6. The official link is [here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache), but for consistency:

Run the following commands in the terminal:

1. Download Certbot

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
sudo mv certbot-auto /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
```

2. Execute Certbot

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --apache
```

If there's an error message, read the warning and run (if you feel comfortable):

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --apache --debug
```

Here, you may be asked to complete some fairly intuitive questions to configure your installation. If not, what worked for me won't work for you. :(

3. Automate Renewal

Test to see if renewing your certificate works:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew --dry-run
```

If so, navigate to your system's crontab (usually somewhere around `/etc/crontab/`) and add the following code to check (and run, if necessary) and auto-renewal at midnight and noon everyday:

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative to set it on nginx:

you can use

```
sudo yum install python2-pip

sudo pip2 install certbot
```

for me is python2.7 so:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

then run

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d your-domain
```

Comment: Not working `-bash: certbot: command not found`